# undefined reference to function in gcc

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to use a C static library but getting the following error while compiling/linking in gcc. The main file test.c needs to call a function from the static library libtest.a

Header file : testcplusplus.h

```
void print_cplusplus(int b);
```

testcplusplus.c :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "testcplusplus.h"
void print_cplusplus(int b) {
printf ("Value of b is %d \n",b);
}
```

Main C file : test.c

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include "testcplusplus.h"
    int main() {
    int a = 2 ;
    print_cplusplus(a);
    }
```

Commands Used :

```
g++ -c -o testcplusplus.o testcplusplus.c
ar rvs libtest.a testcplusplus.o
gcc -o test test.c -L. -ltest      **// Error comes here**
```

Error:

```
    In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `print_cplusplus'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: You have many errors. But to call a function, you need  `print_cplusplus(a);`

Comment: By the way, the error comes from compiling `test.c`, not from linking. The final command does both these things.

Comment: So why is the title of the question “expected expression before ‘int’ in gcc” if the error message is “undefined reference to `print_cplusplus'”?

Comment: Calling your library `libtest` probably isn't the best idea. You specify library locations with `-L`, not `-I`. It'll already find the header if it's in the same directory.

Comment: @ Pascal Cuoq : I did some editing and the title remained unchanged. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @  Paul Griffiths : Thanks sir I incorporated your suggestion. Actually this is just a dummy code I am trying with both C files. In reality I want to implement testcplusplus.c as a C++ file and do the same stuff. Is it possible to do this if testcplusplus.c was a C++ file ?

Comment: @CSamuel: It doesn't make any difference if you're consistent. It can start getting tricky if you start calling C functions from C++ or vice versa, since the calling convention is by default different, the rules are different for initializing static objects, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only specify function parameter types when you declare/define the function, not when you call it. The function call should look like

```
print_cplusplus(a);
```

You also need to include `testcplusplus.h` from `test.c` so that the declaration is available when you call it. The return type of `main` needs to be `int`; and `print_cplusplus` should either have `void` return type, or should return a value.

Finally, you'll need to declare the function `extern "C"` for it to be callable from a C program - but only when compiling C++.

```
// testcplusplus.h
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void print_cplusplus(int b);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir. I tried to incorporate above said changes but still wasn't able to resolve the new error.

Comment: @CSamuel: It needs to be `extern "C"` to be callable from C. See the update.

Answer (score 0):

You don't *rewrite* a variables type when you use it, it's only used in declarations:

```
print_cplusplus(a);
```